# if browser version selector not working

Tags: html, css, browser

my browser version selector below is not calling my css class... and it is not working in the older browsers... someone knows whay, or have a similar code to help me to solve this ? tanks...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class='no-js'>
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport' />
<meta content='' name='description' />
<meta content='' name='author' />
<title>Datacode</title>
<link href="./stylesheets/globals.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css"    />
<link href="./stylesheets/typography.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" />
<link href="./stylesheets/grid.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./stylesheets/ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./stylesheets/forms.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./stylesheets/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./javascripts/terrific-1.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="./javascripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
    /* terrificjs bootstrap */
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $page = $('body');
            var config = {
              dependencyPath: {
                plugin: 'javascripts/'
              }
            };
            var application = new Tc.Application($page, config);
            application.registerModules();
            application.start();
        });
    })(Tc.$);
  //]]>
</script>

 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which stylesheet are the IE classes in? Can you view the stylesheet in your browser via the paths above?

Comment: this below is my stylesheet to my older browsers, .oldie.ie8 .modNav .nav-bar > li {
  position: relative;
}
.oldie.ie8 .modNav .nav-bar > li > a {
  behavior: url("stylesheets/PIE.html");
  position: relative;
}
.oldie.ie8 .modNav .nav-bar > li .sub-wrapper ul.sub {
  behavior: url("stylesheets/PIE.html");
  position: relative;
}

Comment: I'm trying to check the basics. Is your IE stylesheet being picked up? Can you view source, then click on the stylesheet to see if it is viewable in the browser?

Comment: I think your classes are around the wrong way? should be .ie8.oldie but you could just use .ie8 .ie7 etc... ?